# How can I run WebTest request with https?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webtest

I am using Python's [WebTest](http://webtest.pythonpaste.org/en/latest/) with a Google App Engine wsgi application. My issue is that I cannot figure out how to do a https request using WebTest. I need to do a https request in order to test my authentication flow.

Are there any additional arguments I should be passing to this for https?

```
app.get('/path', [params], [headers], [extra_environ], ...)
```

Also, I seem to have found the documentation (top link), but I am wondering where the API reference spec is located. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking at the wrong level. webtest doesn't make any kind of real HTTP request, using SSL or not: it communicates directly with the WSGI application. Whether the network connection is secure or not is between the client and the server, and nothing to do with the WSGI app; it's not something you can test with a tool like webtest.

That said, the API documentation for webtest is [here](http://webtest.pythonpaste.org/en/latest/api.html).